# Turn on device's Location Access Option without asking user

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application for Android KitKat version (minimum API level 19) in which I need to turn on Location Access option of user's device automatically without asking user. I have tried this code (given below) but it pops up a dialog box and ask user. So please tell how can I turn on Device's Location Access without asking user.

**Code:**

```
public static void enableDeviceLocation(final Activity activity) {

    final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity.getApplicationContext()).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    googleApiClient.connect();
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    //All location settings are satisfied.
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    //Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to upgrade location settings
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(activity, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                    }
                    catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        //PendingIntent unable to execute request.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    //Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog not created.
                    break;
            }
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Simply put, you cant

Comment: You can't, for security.  Otherwise you could track a user unnoticed.  That's why on more modern versions you have to even ask at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

On a standard unrooted Android device, you cannot enable any location providers automatically without user involvement, for obvious privacy and security reasons.